# How do I change Magento Success Page XML layout?

Tags: layout, xml, magento-1

This is the content of my layout:

```
<checkout_onepage_success>
    <reference name="content">
        <remove name="checkout.success"></remove>
        <block type="mynamespace_mymodule/cmscontent" name="successpage3" output="toHtml">
            <action method="setData">
                <name>identifier</name>
                <value>contact</value>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

This is part of the content of my cms content block:

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    echo "Hello"; exit();
    $identifier = $this->getData('identifier');
    //..........
    return $html;
}
```

My string "Hello" is never been displayed. I guess smth is wrong with my layout xml configuration. Any idea how do I get my string to be displayed?

Comment: Is your layout referenced by your modules configuration?

Comment: I have this in the config.xml : <layout>
            <updates>
                <mynamespace_mymdoule>
                    <file>mynamespace_mymdoule.xml</file>
                </mynamespace_mymdoule>
            </updates>
        </layout>

Comment: This is probably not the source of your problem, but you should remove `output="toHtml"`, this adds the block as root block.